# Formulario html no me deja subir datos a bdd en phoMyAdmin

Tags: php, html5, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Estoy trabajando en un formulario html para que me envie datos por el metodo **POST** a un archivo vCurso.php pero no me deja ingresar los datos del formulario a la bdd de datos me sale un error que no se puediron mandar los datos.

ya busque error comparando con otros archivos de verificar iguales y no encuentra nada.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>



<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="crearCursosAdmin.php" method="POST">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <div class="x_panel">

                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2>Ingresa los datos </h2>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>

      <div class="x_content">

                    <!-- Inicio de formulario -->
                    <p>Ingrece todos los datos del curso al igual que los datos generales del instructor.</p>
                    <div id="wizard" class="form_wizard wizard_horizontal">
                      <ul class="wizard_steps">
                        <li>
                          <a href="#step-1">
                            <span class="step_no">1</span>
                            <span class="step_descr">
                                              Paso 1<br />
                                              <small>Curso</small>
                                          </span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#step-2">
                            <span class="step_no">2</span>
                            <span class="step_descr">
                                              Paso 2<br />
                                              <small>Instructor</small>
                                          </span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#step-3">
                            <span class="step_no">3</span>
                            <span class="step_descr">
                                              Paso 3<br />
                                              <small>Aviso</small>
                                          </span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                      
                      </ul>





                      <div id="step-1">
                        

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Nombre del Curso 
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                              <input name="nombre_curso" type="text" id="first-name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Descripcion 
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                              <textarea name="descripcion"  maxlength="120"  type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="comentarios" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="middle-name" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Requisito</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                              <input name="requisitos" placeholder="Ejemplo: Saber usar la pc y sus componetes" id="middle-name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" name="middle-name">
                            </div>
                          </div>



                             <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Categoria</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <select name="categoria" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Programacion">Programacion</option>
                            <option value="Redes Informaticas">Redes Informaticas</option>
                            <option value="Diseño Web">Diseño Web</option>
                            <option value="Diseño Grafico">Diseño Grafico</option>
                            <option value="Offimaticar">Offimaticar</option>
                            <option value="Computacion">Computacion</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>



                             <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Tipo de contenido</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <select name="tipo" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Texto y Video">Texto y Video</option>
                            <option value="Texto y Audio">Texto y Audio</option>
                            <option value="Texto">Texto</option>
                            <option value="Video">Video</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>



                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Duracion en Horas
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                              <input name="duracion" id="birthday" class="date-picker form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required" type="number">
                            </div>
                          </div>


                             <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Limite de Alumnos</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <select name="limite" class="form-control">
                            <option value="20">10-20</option>
                            <option value="30">20-30</option>
                            <option value="60">30-60</option>
                            <option value="120">60-120</option>
                           
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Precio en Dollares $ 
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                              <input name="precio" type="text" id="first-name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                            </div>
                          </div>

                       
<!-- aqui termina el formulario 1 -->
                      </div>



                      <div id="step-2">

                   <!--      aqui va el inicio de formulario 2  -->
                        

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Nombre Del Instructor 
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                              <input name="instructor" type="text" id="first-name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label  class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Correo Electronico
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                              <input name="correo" autocomplete="email" type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="middle-name" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Usuario Del Instructor</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                              <input name="usuario_instructor" id="middle-name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" name="middle-name">
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="middle-name" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Telefono</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                              <input name="telefono" maxlength="8" id="middle-name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="tel" name="middle-name">
                            </div>
                          </div>


<!--aqui termina el formulario 2  -->
                       
                      </div>
                      <div id="step-3">
                        <h2 class="StepTitle">Recordatorio</h2>
                        <p>Este curso aun no tiene las lecciones asignadas , el instructor es el encargado de agregar todas las leccioones para poder completar el curso online.
                        </p>
                         <center>
                         <button  type="submit class="btn btn-primary">Crear Curso</button>
                         </center>  

                      </div>

                    
                    </div>     
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php

$mensaje = $_GET['msj'];
if ($mensaje == "si"){
    header('Location:agregarCursosAdmin.php?msj=') ;
} 
if($mensaje == "no"){
    echo "Curso incorrecto";
}
if ($mensaje == "ya"){
    
    
    echo "El Curso ya existe, intente con otro.";

}
?>
</form>  

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
include("conexion.php");


$nombre_curso = $_POST['nombre_curso'];
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
$requisitos = $_POST['requisitos'];
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
$duracion = $_POST['duracion'];
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
$limite = $_POST['limite'];
$precio = $_POST['precio'];
$instructor = $_POST['instructor'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$usuario_instructor = $_POST['usuario_instructor'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$lecciones = $_POST['lecciones'];

$sql="SELECT NOMBRE_C FROM CURSOS WHERE NOMBRE_C='$nombre_curso'";

$result= $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows>0){
         header('Location:agregarCursosAdmin.php?msj=ya') ;
}else{
  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO CURSOS(NOMBRE_C,DURACION,REQUISITOS,CATEGORIA,LIMITE_ALUMNOS,DESCRIPCION,TIPO_CONTENIDO,INSTRUCTOR,CORREO_INSTRUCTOR,PRECIO,NO_LECCIONES,USUARIO,TELEFONO)
  VALUES('$nombre_curso,'$duracion','$requisitos','$categoria','$limite','$descripcion','$tipo','$instructor','$correo','$precio','$lecciones','$usuario_instructor','$telefono')";

 $result2=$conn->query($sql2);

 if($result2 === TRUE){
        header('Location:agregarCursosAdmin.php?msj=si') ;
 }else{
   header('Location:agregarCursosAdmin.php?msj=no') ;
 }
}



?>
```

Comment: Puedes pegar el error  que te da la aplicación?

Comment: me genera el error que  puse que me mostrara si no me ingresa los datos:

Comment: if($result2 === TRUE){
        header('Location:agregarCursosAdmin.php?msj=si') ;
 }else{
   header('Location:agregarCursosAdmin.php?msj=no') ;
 }

Comment: si, pero en que punto se te cae?

Comment: al momento de darle al botón para que me envié los datos

Comment: en la BD no se alcanzan a ingresar los datos verdad?

Comment: exacto no me deja

Comment: el string de conexion a la bd esta ok? lo probaste?

Comment: si esta, aparte utilice ese código cambiando la sql para ingresar otras datos a otras registros si me los envía perfectamente.

Comment: pero si llega al archivo php ? por que en el enunciado dices que se llama ´vCurso.php´ y en form envias ´crearCursosAdmin.php´

Comment: si ya tengo esa dirección es que hice otro formulario para resumir la información

Comment: entonces tu dices que cambiaste el query y si ingreso? si es así, el problema pueda estar en el query o en los datos sintaxis que utilizas de la tabla.

Comment: intenta hacer ese mismo query desde la bd directamente, quizas solo sea un campo mal escrito

Comment: no, utilice ese mismo código solo para que me ingresa datos a otra tabla (cambiando también las direcciones) y si me funciono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba con este query...

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO CURSOS(NOMBRE_C,DURACION,REQUISITOS,CATEGORIA,LIMITE_ALUMNOS,DESCRIPCION,TIPO_CONTENIDO,INSTRUCTOR,CORREO_INSTRUCTOR,PRECIO,NO_LECCIONES,USUARIO,TELEFONO)

VALUES('$nombre_curso','$duracion','$requisitos','$categoria','$limite','$descripcion','$tipo','$instructor','$correo','$precio','$lecciones','$usuario_instructor','$telefono')";
```

al campo `$nombre_curso` le faltaba una (')... me cuentas... By: JJ

Comment: muchas gracias #srJJ , me salvaste!!

Comment: de nada, bro, me alegra haberte ayudado, te recomiendo estar muy pilas de esos pequeños detalles que nos pones traspies... suerte bro...

Comment: habilita en tu server los errores php así podrá ser mas fácil para ti identificar tus errores ;)

Comment: Lo hare ,muchas gracias !!!

Comment: o imprimir por consola el resultado del query, tambien ayuda, o bueno yo lo uso XD